# CSS: Grid columns, ensure that column heights are the same

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to make the image on the left column have the same height as the content on the right? The problem that I'm facing right now is that I want to have responsive popup which height should depend mainly on the right content and the image on the left should have the same height as the content. What am I missing?

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 items-center bg-purewhite rounded-xl shadow authentication-popup lg:grid-cols-auth-popup lg:max-w-[55rem] lg:w-max svelte-q5aaad opened" style="grid-template-rows: auto !important;">
   <div class="w-full h-full relative shrink-0 lg:rounded-l-xl lg:w-fit"> 
      <img class="w-full h-[200px] object-authentication object-cover rounded-t-xl lg:w-[380px] lg:h-full lg:rounded-l-xl lg:rounded-tr-none" style="/*! height: 100% !important; */" src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1677942035529-db39d2a25915?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=928&amp;q=80">
   </div>
   <div class="flex flex-col grow p-6">
      <div class="flex items-center gap-1.5 justify-between">
         <p class="text-primary font-bold text-3xl lg:whitespace-nowrap">Please Sign In</p>
         <i class="close-pm-delete-confirm-popup fa-solid fa-xmark fa-xl text-secondary cursor-pointer"></i>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting the CSS of img to
img {
object-fit: cover;
height: 100%;
}

Comment: Did not work...

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to use flexbox.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper>.left {
  background: #fcc;
}

.wrapper>.right {
  background: #ccf;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Refer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If no fixed height

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.</div>
</div>


.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
  
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
```

Comment: We don't want to set a fixed height

Comment: You can change the height: 5em; to min-height: 5em;

Comment: For some reason the image will not stretch https://i.gyazo.com/1fa234b7209e041c8fff6dffdcdc81a6.png

Comment: You can use flex it auto adjust,

Comment: this example is made with flex

Comment: https://pastebin.com/r8dLrmey